# Restrict list of strongly-typed classes in the new Add View dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Background:

I just updated to the RC of MVC3, and when I went to add a Stongly-Typed View, the list of classes to use was huge, and contains classes in referenced assemblies I really don't ever want to see.

Is there a way to remove assemblies from being considered in the list of models?

For example, I am seeing:

...

Account (company.Nsa.Services.Entitlement)

...

Feature (company.Nsa.Services.DataStore)

...

GetDatabaseListRequest (company.Nsa.Services.DatabaseCharges)

...

TraceMessage (company.IO)

...

There are at least 3600 entries.  "company.Nsa.Services" is a seperate assembly, as it "company".  Both containing lots of classes we use throughout our codebase, but will NEVER be used as a Data View class.

What I am NOT seeing is:

FindViewModel (Company.UI.Admin.ViewModels)

which is a class in the project with the views.  I am not seeing ANY classes from the Company.UI.Admin assembly.

Comment: Could you provide a list or screenshot of the types that you are seeing? And the names (including namespace) of the types that are missing?

Answer (score 1):

No, just start typing and the list will filter until you find the desired class.

Comment: It is just that there are 1000s of classes that show up that don't need to that it takes a long time to populate.  Also, my classes aren't showing up at all (when they did in BETA), that I thought it was because of the size.